# Bootstrap V4 Carousel Navigation Arrow Label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Im using Bootstrap V4 and Im trying to add a label to the Carousel Navigation Arrows. 
I decided to unhide the labels for Screen Readers but I wanted to place them under the arrow centered.

[Carousel Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcU6r.jpg)

Currently the Arrows HTML is like this:

```
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#outlookProfile" role="button" data-slide="prev" onclick="(function(event) {event.preventDefault();})(event)">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span >Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#outlookProfile" role="button" data-slide="next" onclick="(function(event) {event.preventDefault();})(event)">
        <span >Next</span>
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
```

I've tried playing around with CSS setting diferent Display properties, width, floats, etc without success :(

Any suggestion on how I can achieve this?

Thank you very much,
Ralms

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

I've set the the following css properties to the anchor tags using the bootstrap classes:

```
.carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

Next I had to switch the order of the elements on the "control-next", because the way I had it, the label shows up on top.

Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Your answer could be a bit more clear for better understanding.

Comment: I accepted your edit to add formating, but how do you mean more clear? It was a very simple solution, I dont know how to explain it much better :S

Comment: I've edited the answer, hopefully is more clear now :)